# Add item in ListView menu from Page (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, menu, addition

I have Hamburger menu that is implemented using a ListView.This menu is on my MainWindow.I need to add new item in this ListView from Page.When user click on button it`s add new item in listview with data from textboxes.Here is code of Menu
XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" Foreground="#FF5C99D6" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged">
    <ListViewItem x:Name="Page1" Height="60">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Page1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem x:Name="Page2" Height="60">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Page2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

I need add items like this items style.From Page which opened in Frame.
I have some code for add item.It`s work but name of item is like "WPFProject.Page1+NameItem..."

```
((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).ListViewMenu.Items.Add(new NameItem((TypeHere.Text)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ListView` should have its `ItemsSource` property set. Then, you can use a DataTemplate to display the items. You'll also need some sort of `ViewModel` to hold your collection. This will make your life a whole lot easier.

Your `ViewModel`:

```
public class HamburgerMenuViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<NameItem> MenuItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<NameItem>();
}
```

I'm also assuming your `NameItem` looks a bit like this:

```
public class NameItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The view will now have a DataTemplate, which will allow you to only specify what an item in the list looks like once:

```
<HamburgerMenu>
        <HamburgerMenu.DataContext>
            <local:HamburgerMenuViewModel></local:HamburgerMenuViewModel>
        </HamburgerMenu.DataContext>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
              Foreground="#FF5C99D6"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              SelectionChanged="ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged"
              ItemsSource="{MenuItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type NameItem}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                Height="60">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="20 10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </HamburgerMenu>
```

The `ListView` has a ItemsSource set to the DataContext's `ObservableCollection`. when you modify this collection, the ui will be updated to reflect the collection.

The `DataTemplate` is essentially telling the `ListView` how to display every item. Inside the `DataTemplate`, the `DataContext` is an item in the list, not the `DataContext` of the `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm new in WPF (I'm trying to rewrite the program from WinForms to WPF). Could you please explain where the <HamburgerMenu> tag came from? (Sorry for my Eng).If its some framework is Im not using Frameworks for realize menu.

Comment: @Ricarnev this is just a tag I threw in there, but put the `DataContext` on whatever the parent of your `ListView` is.